# Null pointer exception on second attemp of calling toString method

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

I'm given an assignment to make a singly `LinkedList` class with an `add`, `addAtFirst` and `toString` method. Everything is working fine unless I make a second call to `toString` method.

This is the complete class with methods:

```
public class SingleList {

    Node head;
    int size;

public static class Node{

    int data;
    Node next;
    public Node(int data) {
        this.data=data;
        }
    }   

public void add(int data) {
        size++;
    if(head==null) head= new Node(data);

    else {
        Node n= new Node(data);
        Node temp= head;
        while(temp.next!=null) {
            temp= temp.next;
        }
        temp.next=n;
}

    }


public int size() {
    return size;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return head==null;
}

public void insertAtHead(int data) {
    size++;
    Node n= new Node(data);
    n.next=head;
    head=n;
}


@Override
public String toString(){

if(size==0) return"[]";
StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder().append("[");
for(int i=0;i<size-1;i++)
{   sb.append(head.data+",");
    head=head.next;

}
return sb.append(head.data+"]").toString();
}

}
```

This is the driver class code obviously within main body:

```
java

        SingleList sl= new SingleList();
        System.out.println(sl);
        for(int i=0;i<=10;i++) sl.add(i);
        System.out.println(sl);
        System.out.println(sl);
```

The output is this

```
    []
    [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

And then an null pointer exception and shows a sourece line for exception which is this line `sb.append(head.data+",");`

Answer (score 2):

Your `toString()` method is setting the member `head` to null on the first call:

```
for(int i=0;i<size-1;i++)
{ 
    sb.append( head.data + ",");
    head = head.next;
}
```

On the second call to `toString()`, the member `head` is still null. On the first pass through the loop, `head.data` will cause a NullPointerException.

Instead, you could use a local variable.

```
Node node = head;
for(int i=0;i<size-1;i++)
{ 
   sb.append(node.data+",");
   node = node.next;
}
```

And if you're doing that, you could iterate over the nodes, rather than their indices:

```
for ( Node node = head; null != node; node = node.next ) {
   sb.append(node.data+",");
}
```